# Does not exist import android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap;; (What is the easy way to migrate) Does the migration is necessary for any android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, androidx

After migrating to android x via android studio getting annotation issues (What is the easy way to migrate) Does the migration is necessary for any android project?

How can I easily migrate the app in android studio.

error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap;

Comment: Could you add the full output of the build including this error message. That will make it more clear and give more context. Also, your are probably gonna have to provide your build.gradle dependencies

Answer (score 0):

See the [class mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings):

[`android.support.annotation`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings#androidsupportannotation) should rather be: `androidx.annotation`.

And you probably still have (the wrong one) support libraries referenced; eg:

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
```

[Should rather be](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mapping):

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.legacy/legacy-support-v4/1.0.0
implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
```

The same goes for the annotations:

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.annotation/annotation/1.1.0
implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
```

**all of the references** need to be updated.